# Set AngularJS Global before App Initialization

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am currently working in an AngularJS code base where different routes are triggered depending on some `toggle` element attached to every `customer`. In my app, I need to route to different places twice, once, in my `app.js` file, where I manage my state and another time, in a controller when I use the same variable to branch.

I have tried to use a combination of manually bootstrapping and using the `run` method but haven't had any success.

```
var app = angular
    .module('app', ['customer'])
    .run(function (customer) {
        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            customer.myMethod().then(function (enabled) {
                enabled = enabled;
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
            });
        });
    });
```

---

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: enabled ? '/' : '/customer',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        data: {
            title: 'Home'
        }
    })
```

And then in my controller, use the same variable in my `init` method for example:

```
$scope.init = function () {
    if (enabled) { ... }
    else { ... }
}

$scope.init();
```

I notice that the `enabled` variable eventually does get set, but it happens after the state is decided. Is there a way to set a global variable before my AngularJS app starts in order to use it anywhere?

Thanks

Comment: AngularJS framework `.run` functions  execute after `document.ready`, so `document.ready` inside a `.run` function is superfluous. Bootstapping the app from  inside the app doesn't make sense.

Comment: In general with routers, one uses `resolve` functions to delay loading a view until data has arrived from a server.